# Center Navbar Toggle Button (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I for some reason cannot get my Navbar Toggle Button to center. There are multiple threads relating to this issue, but for some reason I can't get it. Some direct help would be useful!

I have the following CSS dedicated towards the button:

```
.navbar-toggle {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  border-width:0;
  border-radius:0;
}

.navbar-header {
  text-align:center;
}
```

And the following HTML dedicated to the button when screen is small:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation </span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Website Title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Petit+Formal+Script" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>

      img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      }

      h1 {
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
        color:#453d51;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:40px;
      }

      .subtitle {
        font-family: 'Petit Formal Script', cursive;
        font-size:60px;
        text-align:center;
        letter-spacing:2px;

      }

      .navbar-default {
        background-color: white;
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left:2px;
        padding-right: 2px;

      }

      .navbar-toggle {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        margin: auto;
        border-width:0;
        border-radius:0;
        }
        .navbar-header {
          text-align:center;
          }

  </style>

</head>


<body>



  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="container">

        <div class=container>
          <img src="C:\Users\mmosl\OneDrive\DOCUMENTS\Portfolio\Logo\logo.png" margin="0" href="index.html" width=25% height=25%>
          <h1> a portfolio by </h1>
          <p class=subtitle> mrs. slater </p>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">

              <span class="sr-only"> Toggle Navigation </span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd provide website but not live. Here is screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_6fmXn_TvcrOS03emFFemVlVEk

Comment: try adding `text-align: center;` to `.navbar-toggle`.

Reminder: you can upload images directly to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks Lewis for your quick reply. That didn't do it for some reason. Thank you for the reminder. Because I signed up today, I haven't posted enough and I am not allowed to upload images, it does not allow me.

Comment: Ah i see, no problem. I would recommend putting the code onto http://jsfiddle.net and then post the link on here so we can all take a look. :)

Comment: I fixed it :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: .navbar-toggle {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-width:0;
        border-radius:0;
        text-align: center;
        }